# Improve my Scala : conditional date time parsing

Tags: scala, idioms

```
object Utility {
    object Time {
        implicit class Regex(sc: StringContext) {
            def r = new util.matching.Regex(sc.parts.mkString, sc.parts.tail.map(_ => "x"): _*)
        }

        case class DTCtxt(val formatter: DateTimeFormatter, tz: DateTimeZone)

        trait BaseRelativeTime { def dt: DateTime }
        case class Today(val dt: DateTime) extends BaseRelativeTime
        case class Yesterday(val dt: DateTime) extends BaseRelativeTime
        case class Absolute(val dt: DateTime) extends BaseRelativeTime

        def parseRelativeDateTime(str: String, dtCtxt: DTCtxt) = {
            println(str)
            val dateTimeNow = DateTime.now()
            val otherDateTimeNow = dateTimeNow.toDateTime(dtCtxt.tz)

            def update_hour(h: String, s: String) =
                if (s == "AM") h.toInt else if(h.toInt == 12) 0 else h.toInt + 12

            str match {
                case r"Today, (\d\d)$h:(\d\d)$m (\w\w)$s" =>
                    Today(otherDateTimeNow.withTime(update_hour(h, s), m.toInt, 0, 0))
                case r"Yesterday, (\d\d)$h:(\d\d)$m (\w\w)$s" =>
                    Yesterday(otherDateTimeNow.minusDays(1).withTime(update_hour(h, s), m.toInt, 0, 0))
                case dt@_ =>
                    Absolute(dtCtxt.formatter.parseDateTime(dt))
            }
        }

        def guardedParseRelativeDateTime(str: String, dtCtxt: DTCtxt) = {
            if(str.isEmpty)
                None
            else
                Some(parseRelativeDateTime(str, dtCtxt))
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is there a better way to expose what type of date time matching occurred to clients, the trait -> case class is a lot of typing.
2. How do I get the case class to implicitly convert to the timezone, I am just using a case class here for annotation and don't want to have to keep typing `.dt`?
3. The regex interpolation code(which I picked up from somewhere random), seems quite foundational, does it exist in the library or do I have to include this in my code?.
4. any other advice to make the code more robust / shorter?

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: aww shucks, this diversification is nuts, did not know that existed ! Hmm it's still in beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take may answer with a grain of salt, YMMV.

**Small things (a bit of code review)**

1. Case classes don't need `val` as that is already implied, that they will be public:

   ```
   case class DTCtxt(formatter: DateTimeFormatter, tz: DateTimeZone)
   case class Today(dt: DateTime) extends BaseRelativeTime
   ```
2. Naming stuff: I find `DTCtxt` a tiny bit cryptic, I would prefer a more verbose name, e.g.: `DateTimeContext`. Also we usually use camel case for methods: `def updateHour`
3. `DateTime.now` can take a `DateTimeZone` parameter: `val dateTimeNow = DateTime.now(dateTimeContext.tz)`

**Answering your questions**

1. and 2.  Not really. The OO approach would be to extend `DateTime`, but the class is final. Another approach is to return a tuple, and the caller can extract the tuple simply in the following way:

   ```
   def createDatetime(...): (DateTime, BaseRelativeTime)
   val (dateTime, typ) = createDatetime(...)
   ```

   I wouldn't say this is a *better* solution, but it's a different. You may find this better. I personally like your approach of the case class encapsulation.
2. see prev.
3. The regex code is nice, but I would rather use JodaTime's parsing capabilities for this. E.g. the pattern `hh:mm aa` matches what you have - if you strip off the Today and Yesterday. E.g.: `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm aa").parseDateTime(timeString).toLocalTime`
4. To make it shorter I think is pointless. If you **really** want short, then just put everything in one line :). I would strive to make it clearer.

   To make it more robust I would use more of JodaTime's LocalDate and LocalTime for the today/yesterday stuff. I would also prefer to remove the implicit StringContext as I feel it's an unnecessary complication.

   Also to make it nicer to use you could make the Context an implicit, so it needs to be declared once.

The final code I came up with:

```
case class DateTimeContext(formatter: DateTimeFormatter, tz: DateTimeZone)

sealed trait DateTimeType { def prefix: String }
case object Today extends DateTimeType { val prefix = "Today, " }
case object Yesterday extends DateTimeType { val prefix = "Yesterday, " }
case object Absolute extends DateTimeType { val prefix = "" }

def createDatetime(dateTimeString: String)(implicit dateTimeContext: DateTimeContext): (DateTime, DateTimeType) = {
  val date = DateTime.now(dateTimeContext.tz).toLocalDate
  val TimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm aa")

  def parseTime(timeString: String) = TimeFormat.parseDateTime(timeString).toLocalTime

  dateTimeString match {
    case today if today.startsWith(Today.prefix) =>
      val time = parseTime(today.stripPrefix(Today.prefix))
      val dt = date.toDateTime(time, dateTimeContext.tz)
      (dt, Today)
    case yesterday if yesterday.startsWith(Yesterday.prefix) =>
      val time = parseTime(yesterday.stripPrefix(Yesterday.prefix))
      val dt = date.minusDays(1).toDateTime(time, dateTimeContext.tz)
      (dt, Yesterday)
    case _ =>
      (dateTimeContext.formatter.parseDateTime(dateTimeString), Absolute)
  }
}
```

Calling it:

```
implicit val dtContext = DateTimeContext(null, DateTimeZone.UTC)
val str = "Yesterday, 11:56 PM"
val (dt, typ) = createDatetime(str)
println(dt) // 2013-11-20T23:56:00.000Z
println(typ) // Yesterday
```

**Conclusion**

I would recommend using what you like from this answer. As I mentioned, I prefer the case class encapsulation and just wanted to demonstrate a different approaches that you could try.